Show or movie where the main character is trying to save wild horses from an evil wizard
It is live action. The main character is female and likely a teenager or young woman.
I watched this around 2007 in an elementary school ethics class, so it may have been made for educational purposes. Even at the time it looked either low budget or dated.
I only recall one episode (or portion; unclear if it was a series or a movie), and the only detail is - as said in the title - there were wild horses on the beach that were somehow in danger or under threat by an evil man. The main character may have been brought there just for that purpose.
Side characters were royalty- or knight-themed, so I believe it was in the fantasy genre. I want to say one was something called a 'Light Knight' (play on night light) or maybe related to playing cards - it gave Alice in Wonderland energy.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Your description makes it sound the the protagonist was not from the same world as the rest of the characters; is that correct?  Was she from contemporary Earth?

I believe so, yes. Her clothing was contemporary.

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Just to get it out of the way, could this be The Last Unicorn?

sounds slightly like Winter's Tale

Not Last Unicorn and doesn't look like Winter's Tale. This was definitely geared towards elementary school children.
Only other details I can think of is I believe the main character was white and had long hair. The horses that the protagonist was trying to save or free lived on a beach or an island.
